# Convert date in unpadded m/d/y format to datetime in python pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I know similar questions have been asked a million times, but I can't actually find this particular answer, which seems like it should be a really common situation in data cleaning.

I have a column of dates as strings without padding and in American layout, so February 19, 2009 is 2/19/09.

I'm trying to convert them to datetime in python pandas

Here's example data:

```
member  state   country         zip         joined .   pet
16081   NY      UNITED STATES   11215       9/4/09 .   parrot
21186   NY      UNITED STATES   5325        8/9/11 .   crunchyfrog
34999   NY      UNITED STATES   11218       11/4/16    lumberjack
34999   NY      FOOBAR STATES   NaN         11/4/16    blind bat
5033    NY      UNITED STATES   11238-1630  11/7/16    norwegianblue
35079   NY      FOOBAR STATES   SW4 9JX     11/13/16 . spanishinq   
35084   NY      UNITED STATES   11217-2181  11/14/16 . spam
```

my latest attempt was

```
for x in df['joined']:
    x = dt.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

which got back "time data '2/16/09' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.joined = pd.to_datetime(df.joined)
print (df)
   member state        country         zip     joined            pet
0   16081    NY  UNITED STATES       11215 2009-09-04         parrot
1   21186    NY  UNITED STATES        5325 2011-08-09    crunchyfrog
2   34999    NY  UNITED STATES       11218 2016-11-04     lumberjack
3   34999    NY  FOOBAR STATES         NaN 2016-11-04      blind bat
4    5033    NY  UNITED STATES  11238-1630 2016-11-07  norwegianblue
5   35079    NY  FOOBAR STATES     SW4 9JX 2016-11-13      panishinq
6   35084    NY  UNITED STATES  11217-2181 2016-11-14           spam
```

You can also specify `format` if necessary:

```
df.joined = pd.to_datetime(df.joined, format='%m/%d/%y')
print (df)
   member state        country         zip     joined            pet
0   16081    NY  UNITED STATES       11215 2009-09-04         parrot
1   21186    NY  UNITED STATES        5325 2011-08-09    crunchyfrog
2   34999    NY  UNITED STATES       11218 2016-11-04     lumberjack
3   34999    NY  FOOBAR STATES         NaN 2016-11-04      blind bat
4    5033    NY  UNITED STATES  11238-1630 2016-11-07  norwegianblue
5   35079    NY  FOOBAR STATES     SW4 9JX 2016-11-13      panishinq
6   35084    NY  UNITED STATES  11217-2181 2016-11-14           spam
```

Comment: I thought having the capital would give me the four digit in the output (which I now feel too foolish to ask about). Thanks!

Comment: You need assign converted datetimes back to dataframe?

Comment: This give me a list of these: numpy.datetime64('2002-07-17T00:00:00.000000000') which I guess I now convert to a format that looks closer to what I started with, but is recognized as a date.

Comment: So now it works nice? Or need convert column `joined` to list of `dates` - `print (df.joined.dt.date.tolist())` ?

Comment: are you often someone's favorite person, because you're my favorite person right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is caused by the fact that %Y is for yyyy representations instead of yy. Try using:

```
dt.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y')
```

Easiest way to apply this to the whole column would be to use the apply function:

```
df.joined = df.joined.apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y'))
```

Comment: I thought having the capital would give me the four digit in the output (which I now feel too foolish to ask about). Thanks!

Comment: They're actually still strings after this.

Comment: This should do the trick, although jezreal has already given a working answer i suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

> "time data '2/16/09' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'"

Because you are using `%Y` instead of `%y`:

```
%y - Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
%Y - Year with century as a decimal number.
```

Comment: I thought having the capital would give me the four digit in the output (which I now feel too foolish to ask about). Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately changing to lower .case still left me with strings.